# Equivalent conditions for a Group $G$ with order $p^2q$ ( with $p>q$ both prime) be abelian.

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

I saw this homework many times, but always asks in the statament that  $p^2 \not\equiv 1$ (mod $q$) and  $q \not\equiv 1$ (mod $p$).

But today in a book text of Galois theory I Saw a similar example that the statament just asks that $q$ doesn't divides $p^2$.

Just using this fact i Tried to prove that exists just one subgroup with order $p^2$ and just one with order $q$

By the first Sylow theorem groups with such order exists, and by the third theorem the number of this groups are of the form $n_{p^2}=1+kp^2,  k\in \mathbb{N}$ and  $n_{q}=1+k'q,  k'\in \mathbb{N}$ with boths dividing the order of $G$.

$n_{p^2}$ divides $p^2$ just for $k=0$ and by the hyphotesis $q\nmid p^2$ how Could I conclude that there is no $k\neq 0$ such that $n_{p^2}\nmid q$?

Analogously how to use this to prove $n_{q}\nmid p^2$?

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  The statement (or question?) in the header is false, clearly.  Take the direct product of $S_3$ and the cyclic group of order $3$, say.

Comment: @Eduardo Silva : (http://www.math.purdue.edu/~lipman/5532011/order-p%5E2q.pdf)

Comment: @lulu, that is indeed true, the statement in the header is incomplete, the objective of the post is to prove the result with a different condition on the primes numbers

Comment: @Yadati Kiran, on the second line is writen that 1+p divides q, why is that true?

Comment: @EduardoSilva : It s because of Sylow theorem: $n_p\equiv1\mod p$ and $n_p|\: |G|$ in particular $n_p|q\implies 1+kp|q$. Here we see that it is possible for $k=1$. Hence the argument follows.

Comment: @Yadati Kiran, but this wouldn't implie that the p groups are no unique? I guess we need this to prove the isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\times\mathbb{Z_q}$, right?

Comment: It should be $n_p=1+kp$ and it must divide $p^2q$. So, $1+kp|q$ and because of $q≢1$ (mod $p$), we get $n_p=1$. This means that we have a unique $p$-sylow of $G$. Also $ \:q\nmid p^{2}-1$ therefore $n_{q} = 1+kq \neq p,\: p^{2}$. So we also have a normal $q$ -Sylow subgroup. So

- $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$

Comment: Please edit your post to ask a clear, coherent question.  The condition that $q$ shouldn't divide $p^2$ doesn't even make sense...the only prime that divides $p^2$ is $p$ and we know $q\neq p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eduardo Silva: $q$ doesn't divide $p^2$ is not enough (in fact, it is equivalent to $p \neq q$), and so Iulu example works as a counterexample. I guess the only thing you can say with your hypoteses is that there is only one Sylow p-Subgroup (since $p>q$, $n_p$ must be $1$, for the next available value is $p+1$, which cannot divide $q$). 
Are you sure there is no other assumption?

Comment: you are right, the exercise must be wrong, i guess that the only condition nedded is that $q\nmid p^2-1$, so we can assume that this was a type mistake